# Is it safe to distribute client_id and client_secret for Google API for an installed application?

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Similar questions have been asked before ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957027/oauth-2-installed-application-client-secret-considerationsgoogle-api),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615372/client-secret-in-oauth-2-0?rq=1)), but not explicitly answered:

Is it safe to store the `client id` and `client secret` credentials obtained for an `Installed application -> Other` for the Google API with the distributed source code of a command line application which will be distributed? Or will it be possible to access user accounts or data *without* the `access_token` granted by user consent?

The Google API [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#installed) specifies that..:

> .. results in a client ID and, in some cases, a client secret, which you embed in the source code of your application. (In this context, the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret.)

it is apparent from other documentation that this is not best practice: the `client_secret` should not even be provided by the service, but it is currently required by the `oauth2` and `googleapiclient` libraries (for Python), and probably by the Google service as well.

The application will use `oauth2` based on these [official examples](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).

References, good explanation or documentation that confirms whether this is truly safe or not is much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of application do you develop (server-side, mobile, single page web application) and what OAuth2 flow do you want to use?

Comment: @JánHalaša: It says in the question, a command line application (which will be distributed), using oauth2 in this way: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app

Comment: actually, here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 2):

**Client Id** is a publicly visible and it is safe to put it in your website, but it is not safe to put your **client** **secret** in js or html code in a website

Comment: How can it be used to gain access to the users account?